# Braids with an infinite number of strings

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, braid-groups

Has anyone developed a theory for braids with an infinite number of strings?

Comment: References here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201303v3.pdf

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Infinitely_generated_braid_groups

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thank you!

Comment: The infinite strand braid group $B_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n}B_{n}$ has more features and hence a richer theory than the finite strand braid groups. The infinite strand braid group $B_{\infty}$ can be endowed with a self-distributive operation $*$ defined by letting $x*y=x\text{sh}(y)\sigma_{1}\text{sh}(x)^{-1}$ where $\text{sh}:B_{\infty}\rightarrow B_{\infty}$ is the group homomorphism defined by $\text{sh}(\sigma_{i})=\sigma_{i+1}$, and $(B_{\infty},*)$ actually contains the free one generator self-distributive algebra. There is no analogue of this in $B_{n}$.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks a lot! Would you have a reference?